# How to set the background color of a table cell with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, gridview

I've written an ASP.net page that uses an ASP GridView to display a table of data.

I would like to write some JavaScript that will color each cell red that contains the value '0'.  I think I can use something like $("td").each or document.getElementsByTagName('td').  I have some CSS I would like to apply to the cells to make them red.

How can I do this with jQuery (or without jQuery) ?

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method makes that very short:

```
$("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "0";
}).css("backgroundColor", "red");
```

Or using a CSS class:

```
$("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "0";
}).addClass("YourRedClass");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("td.td-in-grid-class").each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == "0") {
        $(this).attr("class", "red"); // assume you have css class named "red" 
        $(this).attr("style", "background-color:#ff0000;"); // alternative
    }
});
```

Comment: Consider using `addClass()` and `css()` instead of `attr()` to do it. That way, it won't clear all current classes and styles.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$("td").toggleClass("my_css_class");
```

If you are just rendering data generated server-side, though, then I would apply the class server-side rather than using javascript.

Comment: I was having trouble getting it to render the way I wanted server side.  I thought that client side might make for better frexibility.